# Can I make an exception to the counter in a for loop?

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, counter

I'm trying to make a program to play rock, paper, scissors with a computer. However, part of the assignment is having the player choose the amount of rounds to play with the computer. If there is a tie, the round is not supposed to count towards the game.

My code looks like this -- I'm more focused on the `for` part of the program:

```
int gamePlays = 0;

for (int = 0; i < gamePlays; i++)
{
 // If, else if, and else statements to make the game possible. 
 // Here is an example of part of the code:
if (cpuChoice.equals ("rock"))
{
  if (userChoice.equals ("scissors"))
  {
      System.out.println("Rock beats scissors, computer wins.");
  }
  else if (userChoice.equals ("paper"))
  {
      System.out.println("Paper beats rock, computer wins.");
  }
  else 
  {
      System.out.println("You both chose rock! It's a tie.");
  }
// The rest would else if cpuChoice.equals "paper" and else. 
}
```

How do I exclude the last `else` statement when it's a tie from the counter? I've wrestled with this for a couple hours and can't find any solutions.

Comment: Either --i, or ++gamePlays

Comment: Is the round not supposed to count, or are you supposed to add another round to the total?  I wonder if that matters, but just wanted to clarify your assignment's exact words.   Granted, now that I look at Nate's comment above, he mentioned GamePlays also.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of  `for`  I suggest `while`

```
int i = 0; 
while (i < gamePlays)
{
 // If, else if, and else statements to make the game possible. 
 // Here is an example of part of the code:
if (cpuChoice.equals ("rock"))
{
  if (userChoice.equals ("scissors"))
  {
      System.out.println("Rock beats scissors, computer wins.");
      i++; // increment only when there is result
  }
  else if (userChoice.equals ("paper"))
  {
      System.out.println("Paper beats rock, computer wins.");
      i++; // increment only when there is result
  }
  else 
  {
      System.out.println("You both chose rock! It's a tie.");
     // don't increment if no result
   }
// The rest would else if cpuChoice.equals "paper" and else. 
}
```

}

Comment: First, you're missing the `i` on the first line. Also, you don't need to change `for` loop to `while`, just leave increment section blank: `for (int i = 0; i < gamePlays; )`. Advantage: The loop variable `i` is scoped to the loop, not to the surrounding (method?) block.

Comment: This is a great solution (changing it to a while statement). I ended up just adding an: i = i - 1;. at the end of the else statements, but this would have worked as well. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` loop creates a variable `i` which you can modify in the body of the `for` loop. If you want the code to have the effect of *not* incrementing the counter when the user ties with the CPU, then decrement `i` where you need it:

```
int gamePlays = 0
for (int i = 0; i < gamePlays; i++) {
   ...
   else {
     // this is where you handle ties
     System.out.println("You tied with CPU");
     i--; // decrement the counter
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you geoff! This is what I ended up doing. When I realized how simple the solution was, I was kicking myself! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

if that happens, just put

```
i--;
```

for that statement. Then the round would not be included.
For your question.

```
for (int = 0; i < gamePlays; i++)
{
 // If, else if, and else statements to make the game possible. 
 // Here is an example of part of the code:
if (cpuChoice.equals ("rock"))
{
  if (userChoice.equals ("scissors"))
  {
      System.out.println("Rock beats scissors, computer wins.");
  }
  else if (userChoice.equals ("paper"))
  {
      System.out.println("Paper beats rock, computer wins.");
  }
  else 
  {
      System.out.println("You both chose rock! It's a tie.");
      i--;
  }
// The rest would else if cpuChoice.equals "paper" and else. 
}
```

This will make the 'i' to remain the same since your 'i' will be incremented after the loop.

Comment: You don't need the i--;

Comment: I would recommend deleting this answer. It;'s an except copy of @AJ. except you added an incorrect line of code.

Comment: oops sorry @AJ. I mistakenly copied your code, I thought I copied the for loop that the question owner asked.

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis I finally see what you guys are talking about, yep my mistake. I was changing the owner's code and seems like I mistakenly copy the Aj's one

Answer (score 0):

First, your message it wrong. When `cpuChoice.equals("rock")` and `userChoice.equals("paper")`, then correct message is:

> Paper beats rock, **player** wins.

Also, if `gamePlays = 0`, there will be no game. ;-)

Since you probably want to keep score too, just use the scores:

```
int cpuWins = 0;
int userWins = 0;
while (cpuWins + userWins < gamePlays) {
    if (cpuChoice.equals("rock")) {
        if (userChoice.equals("scissors")) {
            System.out.println("Rock beats scissors, computer wins.");
            cpuWins++;
        } else if (userChoice.equals("paper")) {
            System.out.println("Paper beats rock, player wins.");
            userWins++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("You both chose rock! It's a tie.");
        }
    } else ...
        ...
    }
}
if (cpuWins > userWins)
    System.out.println("Computer is champion.");
else if (cpuWins < userWins)
    System.out.println("Player is champion.");
else
    System.out.println("There is no champion.");
```